# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.4.REL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I imported a maven project in eclipse , whenever I am trying to build,install,clean the application then we are getting below error-
[image]

Actually our project is running on remote machine so we can not close the VPN . I searched
on stackoverflow some one is saying that I need to provide proxy detail in .m2/setting.xml.
I also provide the proxy detail but still we are getting same issue.
And in my pom.xml file getting error alert on two element first on parent and second on project element .
please find below snippet for the pom.xml file

[image]

Please provide any solution -

Comment: See the blocking http access in the release notes: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html

Comment: Apart from that... the usage of such an old spring boot verison is not recommended ... https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support...